# Find $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-2x+xe^{-2x}}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I came across the problem of finding the sum

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k)^k}$ and I proved that it is equal to the integral $$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-2x+xe^{-2x}}dx$$ but I'am unable to solve this integral even though I can find numerical approximations using Wolfram.

I welcome any solutions(Exact Value of the sum),comments,suggestions and possible generalisations to this problem.

Comment: Maybe it's time to define a new special function: $$\operatorname{Sun}(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n} {n^n} $$In particular your sum is just $\operatorname{Sun} \left(\frac12\right) $ :)

Comment: Yes ,unless we know something nice (or find something nice) about this function,this is not heading anywhere.

Comment: @Zacky No need to define a new function $\operatorname{Sun}(z)$ as, funny enough, it is actually related to the *Sophomore dream function* $\operatorname{Sphd}(\alpha;z)$ :)

Answer (score 4):

Interestingly, your sum is related to the so-called *[Sophomore dream function](http://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum/attachment.php?aid=788)* $\operatorname{Sphd} (\alpha;x)$ which is defined as
$$\operatorname{Sphd}(\alpha;x) = \int_0^x t^{\alpha t} \, dt.$$
Of course, whether you accept this function as a member of the "standard" canon of special functions or not is still debatable.

In any event, to see this, enforcing a substitution of $x \mapsto -\frac{1}{2} \ln x$ in your integral yields
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty e^{-2x + xe^{-2x}} \, dx &= \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 e^{-\frac{x}{2} \ln x} \, dx\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 x^{-x/2} \, dx\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \operatorname{Sphd} \left (-\frac{1}{2};1 \right ).
\end{align}
Thus
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n n^n} = \frac{1}{2} \operatorname{Sphd} \left (-\frac{1}{2};1 \right ).$$

---

**Comments**

1. In general
   $$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n^n} = x \int_0^1 x t^{-xt} \, dt = x \operatorname{Sphd} (-x;1).$$
2. For a discussion on what "counts" as a known function, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2116934/what-counts-as-a-known-function/2116984#2116984).
3. Finally, as they say, a function is only as *important* as it is *useful*.